# Capture web driver network traffic across all browsers

Tags: selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, tcpmon, browsermob

I want to capture all the network calls from Web Driver in Java. I am not doing any UI testing, just testing JS execution and, requests and responses of some network calls.

I tried using Browser Mob as is suggested in most forums, but I need it to work across all browsers. It worked flawlessly with Firefox, but I was facing some issues with the others. Safari driver doesn't event support a Proxy capability.

I don't want to use Fiddler as it involves some manual steps around invoking and storing the calls. Whereas, Browser Mob being an in-code proxy can be integrated in a more smoother fashion.

I also tried using the RC-like package included in Selenium standalone server package. But, I have some HTTPS calls and some nested iframes in cross domains. I am particularly interested in some cross domain POST call and it doesn't work out that well. Also, people keep saying it's not recommended to use that package.

So, I had a solution where we can use a standalone proxy server running on a machine. Using host entries, we'll point Web Driver to hit the proxy instead of the actual server. The proxy will record all the incoming calls and route them to the actual server host. Later, I can make a request to the proxy which will return me all the calls it intercepted. I am not sure whether it's still called a proxy or a router.

I came across TCPmon, but it's no longer being supported. Does anyone know some similar tools that could run on Unix systems or any alternate solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We modified the Fiddler rules script to include a new exec action. If you use their native script editor, it also provide auto complete features and we were comfortably able to get around it. The syntax is similar to that of JavaScript.
The Fiddler package comes with a ExecActions.exe which can be used to pass console arguments to a running Fiddler instance using the command prompt.
The code we wrote processed all the sessions captured by Fiddler and wrote it to a file in a custom JSON format and later used GSON to deserialize it.
Please let me know, if you want further details.